# ¿Es posible borrar el caché de una URL específica con NGINX?

Tags: nginx

Estoy usando NGINX como servidor inverso, pero tengo un problema al hacer cambios en una página de mi sitio web, los cambios no se ven hasta que limpio todo el caché de NGINX, lo que hace que limpie todo mi sitio y no solo en la URL donde estoy trabajando

Entonces, me gustaría saber si es posible borrar solo el caché de una URL específica.

He configurado la parte de contenido dinámico pero la carga de la página supera los 600ms y cuando es solo contenido estático carga en 200ms.

Usé esta línea de comando en mi terminal pero tampoco funcionó:

```
grep -lr 'https://example.com/blog/name-of-blog.php$' /var/cache/nginx/*
```

Además ya intenté configurar desde el archivo .htaccess y no ha ido como esperaba.

Espero que puedas ayudarme.